# Facing openrave installation error

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, ros, openrave

I am facing a problem while installing **openravepy module** , by following official guide and instructions on other blog sites.
It is really complicated.

Can someone give me one package installation instructions 
using ubuntu 14.04.4,
ROS indigo distribution ,
and script  that I am trying to run is in catkin_workspace

Comment: If you really want an answer, it might be helpful to explain what kind of problem your are facing with any detail needed.

Comment: 'em running this script https://github.com/simon0793/pr2_simulation (simulation_one_cup_motion_queue.py) which is importing (arm.py) but in (arm.py) there is a line (import openravepy as rave) thiat is creating problem for me i tried a lot to solve that issue
main point: ( 'em trying to simulate pr2 robot in gazebo , ROS )
i think this is enough info

Answer (score 0):

I am using OpenRAVE over Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo.

I followed this tutorial [here](https://fsuarez6.github.io/blog/openrave-trusty/). Below is extraction from the tutorial provided.

### Install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake g++ git ipython octave python-dev python-h5py python-numpy \
python-pip python-scipy python-sympy qt4-dev-tools zlib-bin
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libassimp-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavformat-dev     \
libboost-all-dev libboost-date-time-dev libbullet-dev libfaac-dev libfreetype6-dev    \
libglew-dev  libgsm1-dev liblapack-dev libmpfi-dev libmpfr-dev libode-dev libogg-dev  \
libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0 libqhull-dev libqt4-dev libsoqt-dev-common libsoqt4-dev      \
libswscale-dev libswscale-dev libvorbis-dev libx264-dev libxml2-dev libxvidcore-dev
```

Install collada:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install collada-dom-dev
```

### OpenSceneGraph

```
cd ~/git
git clone https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph.git --branch OpenSceneGraph-3.4
cd OpenSceneGraph
mkdir build; cd build
cmake .. -DDESIRED_QT_VERSION=4
make -j `nproc`
sudo make install
```

### FCL - The Flexible Collision Library

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:imnmfotmal/libccd
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libccd
```

Build and install FCL 0.5.0:

```
cd ~/git
git clone https://github.com/flexible-collision-library/fcl
cd fcl; git reset --hard 0.5.0
mkdir build; cd build
cmake ..
make -j `nproc`
sudo make install
```

### sympy Version

Downgrade sympy so that IKFast works properly:

```
pip install --upgrade --user sympy==0.7.1
```

### Build OpenRAVE from source:

```
cd ~/git
git clone https://github.com/rdiankov/openrave.git
cd openrave; git reset --hard 81ec501
mkdir build; cd build
cmake -DODE_USE_MULTITHREAD=ON -DOSG_DIR=/usr/local/lib64/ ..
make -j `nproc`
sudo make install
```

Test your installation by running:

```
openrave.py --example graspplanning
```